# Segmentation faults after installing .deb packages

Tags: pi-zero, dpkg

I have a Pi Zero (not WiFi) running Raspberry Pi OS (2023-05-03).

I have no way of connecting it to the internet but I wanted to install two packages:

- feh
- unclutter

So I downloaded both (armfh binaries) from the Debian repo (bullseye stable releases), and installed them using dpkg -i.

After resolving 1 dependency issue (by installing yudit-common, required by feh), both applications installed OK.

However, when I go running either of them from the CLI (no matter which arguments I pass), they both return "Segmentation fault".

Does anyone have any clue why this could be? It seems coincidental that both fail in the same way.

Note I've tried with 2 different SD cards to rule out a disk issue.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 1):

It is far from clear what you actually did, but if you downloaded from Debian they won't run on a Pi Zero as Debian has never supported ARM6.

Raspberry Pi OS produces its own ARM6 binaries.